# Laravel 9 Vite 3 app.css newly added CSS rule doesn't work

Tags: php, css, laravel, vite

I recently encountered a problem regarding the **app.css**. I have used Tailwind for my CSS and it was working previously. Weird problem is that when I try to add new CSS rule in app.css, using it doesn't work.

- Laravel 9.34.10
- Vite 3.1.7
- Tailwind 3.1.8

app.css (.button-success is working, newly added .button-info doesn't)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .button-success {
    @apply 
    rounded-none 
    bg-green-600 
    shadow-lg 
    text-white
  }
  .button-info {
    @apply 
    rounded-none 
    bg-blue-600 
    shadow-lg
  }
}
```

DistributionDataTable.php (snippet of the Yajra datatable buttons)

```
          'buttons' => [
            [
              'extend' => 'print',
              'text' => 'PRINT',
              'className' => 'button-success',
              'exportOptions' => [
                'columns' => 'th:not(:first-child)'
              ]
            ],
            [
              'extend' => 'copy',
              'text' => 'COPY',
              'className' => 'button-info',
              'exportOptions' => [
                'columns' => 'th:not(:first-child)'
              ]
            ],
          ]
```

database/index.blade.php (PRINT button only has the CSS style, COPY button doesn't)
[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf7hY.png)

Command sequence:

1. php artisan optimize:clear
2. npm run dev
3. npm run build

I have also tried Cache Clearing the browser using Ctrl + F5, even using other browsers. The problem still persists. Would kindly request for your assistance on this matter as I am pulling hairs on where the problem is. Thank you